# Sum of n terms of an A.P. is $3n^2+5n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If sum of n terms of an A.P. (Arithmetic Progression) is $3n^2+5n$ then which of its terms is $164?$ Options are $26/27/28/$none-of-these

I've posted my answer below but I am looking for a shorter/quicker solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find $a_n=S_{n+1}-S_{n}$ if the first term starts at $n=0$ and then easily find the term that is equal to $164$

$$a_n=3(n+1)^2+5(n+1)-3n^2-5n=6n+8$$
$$6n+8=164 \implies n=26$$

If the first terms starts at $n=1$, one simply has to add one too the answer: $N=n+1$ or use $S_{n}-S_{n-1}$ which would result in $N=27$

In this case, one can deduce that the starting point is n=1 because the $S_0=0$ is inconsistent with the progression which has an initial value of $8$ not zero. So, the final value is $n=27$

Comment: but it's giving me n=26

Comment: Yeah I got the same answer.

Comment: with $S_n-S_{n-1}$, I am getting 27

Comment: Yeah, that is because it matters if we are starting $n$ with $0$ or $1$. With $S_{n-1}$ we are starting with $1$. In this case, I believe starting with $n=1$ is more appropriate. So, its better to use $S_{n}-S_{n-1}$. At any rate, such a question must specify the initial condition of $n$

Comment: So, out of the given options (26/27/28), ur answer is 26? but that's wrong as the answer is 27

Comment: Please read what I said: "starting with $n=1$ is more appropriate" because an initial sum of zero  is not consistent with the progression

Comment: ok, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is first term, $d$ is common difference and $l$ is last term.

$3n^2+5n=\frac n2(a+l)\implies 6n+10=8+l\implies l=6n+2=a+(n-1)d\implies 6n-6=(n-1)d\implies d=6.$

$164=a+(n-1)d\implies 156=(n-1)6\implies n=27$